# When to use "Linq to sql"?

Tags: linq-to-sql, ado.net, compare

What are the pro's and con's of using "Linq to SQL" and core ADO.NET technology for access databases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL vs ADO.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671179/linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net)

Comment: or [What are the advantages of LINQ to SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593808/what-are-the-advantages-of-linq-to-sql)

Comment: and see also [Entity Framework vs LINQ to SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantage

- No need to create business objects dbml files will do for you
- No need to worry about writing queries because linq2sql convert your statment in efficient queries
- Important is **Lazy Loading** of related objects

Disadvantage

- Disconnect linq is not supported i.e you cannot deatch you objects form DataContext object. for more detail : [Most efficient way to update with LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872380/most-efficient-way-to-update-with-linq2sql)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same view point as this post, I've yet to find any major disadvantages of Linq.

I have built a number or application and websites using Linq and found it to be extremlly simple to use

http://forums.asp.net/t/1520157.aspx
comment by BoogleC

Regards
Sp

Answer (score 0):

Id also be carefull about how you write you LINQ statement. Sometimes its better to compile your Linq rather than not as every single run of the Linq query is fully parsed every time it happens.  See below linq

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/compiled-or-bust.html

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend LINQ to SQL at all as it is effectively dead (you don't want to be writing legacy code, right?). Microsoft is no longer developing it and they recommend using the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723.aspx) instead (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc298428.aspx)), however, if you are interested in using an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), I would strongly recommend looking at [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx).

Comment: There are reasons why you may choose one over the other described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161164.aspx